# How can I provide code completion information from a macro?

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, code-completion, content-assist

I am creating some macros for a class that extends `scala.Dynamic`. These macros looks like:

```
class MyProxy extends scala.Dynamic {
  final def selectDynamic(field: String): MyProxy = macro ...
  final def updateDynamic(field: String)(value: Any): Unit = macro ...
}
```

These macros works fine. But a `MyProxy` only allows a set of limited members accessing, and I want these members are listed from Scala IDE's content assist and REPL console's Tab key.

Because `MyProxy` instances themselves are created by macros, I wonder if there is any attribute like `setCodeCompletionType` that can be set from the macros that create `MyProxy`, helping REPL and Scala IDE's code completion (and does not affect the generated Java byte code). Then I would have a macro like this:

```
def newMyProxyInstanceImpl(c: Context)(...): c.Expr[MyProxy] = {
  import c.universe._
  val tree: Tree = ...
  val codeCompletionHint: Type = RefinedType(...)
  tree.setCodeCompletionType(codeCompletionHint)
  c.Expr(tree)
}
```

How can I hack the Scala compiler to make this approach work?

Comment: This behavior is not yet implemented. If you really want to hack scalac then you should ask this question on scala-internals, where all the compiler, macro and IDE gurus are sitting. No one can give you a full answer (which lists all the things to do) here.

Comment: Some macro folks check stack overflow as well :)

Comment: Is a compiler plugin able to inject into the code completion process?

Comment: Not sure, probably not, but that you'll have better luck asking at scala-ide-dev

Comment: In general, macro-powered completion is one of the things I've long been thinking about, but never got time to implement. If you figure out a mechanism to communicate completion info to the IDE please post back here.

Comment: Can I determine whether the macro is evaluated by IDE, like `if (c.getClass.getPackage.toString.startsWith("scala.tool.eclipse.")) return reify { ??? : { def memberForCodeCompletion0: MyProxy; def memberForCodeCompletion1: MyProxy; } }`?